# Combine 2 queries with LEFT JOIN and 3 tables

Tags: sql-server, left-join

First Left JOIN with 2 tables (project_reviews & project_review_remarks)

```
SELECT pr.review_id,client_name,improvement_areas, strengths
FROM project_reviews pr
LEFT JOIN project_review_remarks pra ON pr.review_id = pra.review_id
WHERE review_status IN ('COMPLETED') 
ORDER BY review_date DESC;
```

[image]

Second Left JOIN with 2 tables (project_reviews & project_review_remarks)

```
SELECT pr.review_id, COUNT(pra.action_item_id) AS actions
FROM project_reviews pr
LEFT JOIN project_review_action_item pra ON pr.review_id = pra.review_id
GROUP BY pr.review_id;
```

[image]

In both the queries, project_reviews is a common table,

> IN first Query is ONE-ONE relationship
> IN second Query is ONE-MANY relationship (WHERE I COUNTED it many rows using group by)

I want to merge both queries into one query, because project_reviews is a common table with review ID and show the count of action_item into one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add these code to first query.

- In select add `COUNT(pra.action_item_id) AS actions`.
- Add `LEFT JOIN project_review_action_item pra ON pr.review_id = pra.review_id`. Make sure that your both `LEFT JOIN tables` has different `alias` as I have updated `project_review_remarks`**`prr`**.
- Add `GROUP BY` with all `columns` from `SELECT` like `GROUP BY pr.review_id, client_name, improvement_areas, strengths`.
- To `GROUP BY` with `TEXT` columns you can cast it to `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` whichever you think appropriate.

Check complete query below.

```
SELECT  pr.review_id, 
        client_name, 
        CAST(improvement_areas AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS improvement_areas, 
        CAST(strengths AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS strengths, 
        COUNT(pra.action_item_id) AS actions
FROM project_reviews pr
LEFT JOIN project_review_remarks prr
    ON pr.review_id = prr.review_id
LEFT JOIN project_review_action_item pra
    ON pr.review_id = pra.review_id
WHERE pr.review_status IN ('COMPLETED')
GROUP BY pr.review_id, 
         client_name, 
         CAST(improvement_areas AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 
         CAST(strengths AS VARCHAR(MAX))
ORDER BY review_date DESC;
```

Comment: I cannot make a group by with improvement_areas, strengths columns, because those are text type

Comment: To `GROUP BY` with `TEXT` columns you can cast it to `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` whichever you think appropriate. Updated answer also for same.